# Do the internal inconsistencies of Futurama ever cause it to suffer?

Tags: futurama

> There are some universes which claim or pretend to be consistent and aren't (Star Wars), some which try but know they can't and do their best (Star Trek), some that are consistent, but likely due to a limited run (Firefly, either Galactica), *and then ones that want to entertain and don't worry about consistency, and **Futurama** is in the last category.*

~[TangoOversway](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4997589#4997589)

From this I want to know two important things

1. Has the Futurama fandom ever reacted negatively to one of its many consistency hiccups?
2. Was there ever a retcon of a consistency error with the purpose of placating an angry fanbase?

(Remember, as ever, '*no*' is an ok answer)

Comment: I don't believe there is a non subjective answer, cause to each his own. The consistency or lack of never has bothered me in _any_ show, book as long the main purpose was met, to entertain me. I don't need consistency for that.  It's fun to see connections and easter eggs, but not important. This is a personal choice/like and that is all you will find, there is no one size fits all answer to this.

Comment: Inconsistency is one of Futurama's creative devices. Episode 1 lays the groundwork when Bender re-attaches his arms. Both his arms fall off, bender picks up his right arm with his left, attaches it, then picks up his left arm with his right, and attaches it. You expect it to be inconsistent, and the stage is set. If you use inconsistency as a tool, why would it ever directly harm you?

Comment: @GorchestopherH I don't know, that's why I'm asking about it. And I don't mean the small scale inconsistency that you mentioned I'm wondering if there is some larger inconsistancy at work. If not *that is still an answer*

Comment: Is your misspell of Tango's name intentional?

Comment: @bitmask no, I'm just a terrible person....

Comment: This is an excellent question - not just because I'm credited with the quote, but because it addresses something that's a big part of _Futurama_.  While there have been a ton of trivial questions and questions about events that can change depending on the episode, this asks about whether the flux in canon matters to this show.  Unfortunately, people don't upvote good questions nearly as much as they upvote mediocre answers.

Comment: @TangoOversway They upvote interesting questions they can answer satisfactorily. And I can't blame them for that.

Comment: This question is difficult to answer as currently worded. Limiting the question to a single inconsistency and properly defining how to measure "fan backlash" would help. However, that's still about subjective reactions to a series rather than a question with a factual answer than could be answered directly by the source material or interviews with the show creators. I do not think "How does Justin Bieber feel about Greedo shooting first?" is a good fit for this site. Changing the question to "Is there a reason that concept X introduced in episode Y was contradicted in episode Z?" is better.

Comment: @TangoOversway "mediocre answers" is the worst spelling for "HP questions" I have ever seen.

Comment: @TangoOversway: Maybe you're confusing two things. While this is a terribly interesting *point* about Futurama, that would be great to have an answer to, it is in itself probably very far from being able to produce a constructive, objective answer that is not based on personal speculation. Therefore it is not necessarily a good *question*. I still up voted it (while I *should* have VTC'd it) because I'm trapped in the same confusion.

Comment: @bitmask: Thank you for continuing the discussion by disagreeing with me and providing good points -- instead of just trying to shout louder!  That's an interesting point.

Comment: @TangoOversway: Thank *you* for bringing up the matter in the first place. However, I think this verges on a more general an quite more important issue. To what degree can we determine a question's quality depending on what answers it can be expected (by *educated* guesses) to generate. To make it more obvious; you could ask "What is the *true* meaning of life" -- That question has the same properties (while it also has the property of being off-topic, but disregard that). The problem is, only because I don't think there is an answer, maybe someone out there indeed *does* have one? Go meta?

Comment: Queue meta [discussion](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/1934/3804)

Comment: Thought I should point out, that even though it's almost the only kind of answer I give, I don't *like* giving the "no" answer. Questions like these beg any kind of evidence to overturn the token "no". To put it more convoluted: Lack of proof of it is rarely accepted as proof of the lack of it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No**

While no statistical data was ever released linking viewership to appearances of large plot inconsistencies, considering the type of series Futurama is, the answer is no.

As I mentioned in my comment, inconsistency is one of Futurama's creative devices. Episode 1 lays the groundwork when Bender re-attaches his arms. Both his arms fall off, bender picks up his right arm with his left, attaches it, then picks up his left arm with his right, and attaches it. You expect it to be inconsistent, and the stage is set. If you use inconsistency as a tool, why would it ever directly harm you?

Note that Futurama may have a bit of an over-arching story, or even smaller arcs at times, but the main focus of them is propagate comedic situations, made more fond due to reference.

The drive of the series has as little to do with a consistent story line. To compare it to something else, I'd say Futurama is as likely to be harmed by its inconsistent plot as checkers is abandoned by people who prefer green over red.

Comment: "If you use inconsistency as a tool, why would it ever directly harm you?" Perhaps you are left-handed? ;)

Answer (score 2):

The answer would be no. They don't care that they are inconsistent and the fans don't care either. I think they make an effort though. In the pilot, when the countries are counting down in the future, the french speak english. Later on, the Professor's machine translates into a dead language; french. However, there are scenes where french is spoken.